# Right triangle inside a square

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Hello I'm trying to prove the following
Let ABCD be a square where X is the midpoint of segment AB and BY = (1/4)BC  where DXY is a triangle 
Prove DXY is a right triangle (using coordinate approach)

[Diagram of what im trying to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU9Yr.png)

Now I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem, My idea on approaching the proble is to show XY and XD have negative reciproals of one another i.e same slope just one is negative and one is positive. Yet I  am unsure because of the whole square that encompasses the triangle is supposed to used.

Comment: The question says "using coordinate approach." Where does it say you must use "the whole square"? It's not clear what that even means. But in order to get slopes you must use points on all four sides of the square ($X$ on one side, $Y$ on another, $D$ on the last two sides) which is about as close to "the whole square" as you can reasonably expect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way to solve the problem: Our aim is to prove that $\angle YXD=90^\circ$

Let, the side length of the square be $l$.

As given (See diagram), $AX=BX=\frac{l}{2}$ and $BY=\frac{1}{2}BX=\frac{1}{2}AX$. Let, $\angle BYX=p,\angle BXY=q, \angle AXD=r, \angle ADX=r$.

Then clearly $r+s=90^\circ$. Also $\frac{BY}{BX}=\frac{XA}{AD}=\frac{1}{2}\implies q=s$ and since $\angle A=\angle B=90^\circ$ hence $p=r$. Thus $q+r=90^\circ\implies\angle XYD=90^\circ$. This completes the proof.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

[image]Let the side of square be $a$ and mark the square ABCD clockwise so that origin be at D, we have:

$(x, y)_X=(a/2, a)$

$(x, y)_Y=(a, 3a/4)$

Then:

$DY^2=a^2+(3a/4)^2=\frac{25a^2}{16}$

$DX^2=(a/2)^2+a^2=\frac{5a^2}{4}$

$XY^2=(a-a/2)^2+(3a/4-a)^2=\frac{5a^2}{16}$

$XY^2+DX^2=\frac{5a^2}{16}+\frac{5a^2}{4}=\frac{25a^2}{16}=DY^2$

So the triangle is right angle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be an origin, $B(0,4),$ $C(4,4),$ $D(4,0)$.$

Thus,  $X(0,2)$ and $Y(1,4)$ and

$$m_{XY}\cdot m_{XD}=\frac{2-4}{0-1}\cdot\frac{2-0}{0-4}=-1,$$
which says $\measuredangle YXD=90^{\circ}.$

Here $m_{XY}$ is a slope of $XY$.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach is valid and is probably the easiest way to solve this problem. 
Let's compare the slopes of the two lines $XY$ and $XD$. Remember that our slope can be written as $$m = \frac{\triangle y}{\triangle x}$$, where $\triangle y$ is the change in $y$, and $x$ is the change $x$.

Now the slope of $XY = \frac{2}{1} = 2$

Similarly, the slope of $XD = \frac{-2}{4} = \frac{-1}{2}$

Multiplying the slopes together, we see that $2 \cdot \frac{-1}{2} = -1 $, and therefore, our two lines are perpendicular

Quick Note: All calculations made were based on the diagram given above